# Initiate the radio button name from javascript in inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to assign the radio button value from javascript variable, in inline html. Because I have lot of radio button, and I have a situation to save the radio button name in localstorage, so should I need to give the radio button name unique.If I change every radio button name manually, it take more time.

I have tried

```
<script>
var sample=="XXID";
</script>

<input type="radio" name='"javascript:sample"+n1'/>
```

I have plan to using unique name on the every html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you tagged the Question with `jQuery`, here would be an approach for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sample = "XXID";
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function(index){
        $(this).attr('name', sample + 'n' + index);
    });
)};
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gxh5L2ka/)

**Reference**

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: any possible to error occur? because in this method after initiate the html element only can access!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing a function that will return the name of the radio button. Something like:

```
<script> function add_name(){return sample"+n1';} </script>
```

Also you have a typo on the variable declaration. In the script is *sampe* and in the markup is *sample*.

Call the **add_name()** function in the name attribute and configure it to work for your specific needs.

Comment: I edited the answer. Just call the function in the html where you want to add the names of the tags.